# Samsung printer (ML-1640) margin problem

Tags: printer, laser-printer, margins

I just got a new laser printer, Samsung ML-1640, and it has once again confirmed my experience that Samsung printers suck badly.

The printer prints fine, except that the top margin is set at random, usually very small, cutting text on the top of page off. I tried updating firmware, getting new drivers, but nothing helped. I tried changing paper types, and it seemed that with the paper set as "plain" it was OK, but I just tried printing again after letting the printer rest for the night, and wasted 6 pages until I managed to print 2 boarding passes...

Is there anything else I could try to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Windows 7 64bit drivers and installed samsung smart panel. That fixed the problem for me.